# After assigning one variable to another, why does changing one not change the other?

Tags: java

```
public class IntList {
    private IntNode _head;
    public IntList() {
        _head = null;
    }
 }
```

I created a class called IntList. IntList contains a method to search for an IntNode object with a specified int value. This is the method:

```
public boolean findElementInList(int value) {
    IntNode currentNode = this._head;

    while (currentNode.getValue() != value && 
           currentNode.getNext () != null) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }

    return (currentNode.getValue() == value);
}
```

After the method finishes, the original `_head` instance variable is intact--but why? `currentNode` points to the `_head` in the method (aliasing) and every change done to `currentNode` should also be reflected in `_head` (every time we run `currentNode = currentNode.getNext();`).

This is the code for `getNext()` :

```
public IntNode getNext( ) {return _next;}
```

Comment: currentNode is another reference to head, and you are changing that reference to next element in the list by calling _head.getNext(), head will not change, unless your getNext() somehow modifies head

Comment: what does `getNext()` return? please include the code for `IntNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the value of your head to currentNode at the beginning. Think of it as 2 different pointers point to the same value in memory. But then you keep assigning the next value in the list to your currentNode while _head remains the same. BTW if you change your head value you will lose the head of your list.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed in the beginning I point to ` _head` but then currentNode points to `currentNode.getNext()`

Answer (score 0):

You never change the original `_head`. You just instantiate `currentNode` which points to `_head`. If you want to change `_head` you should at the end change your head with a different value and not just point to it. For example `_head = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `head` instance variable stays intact because you do not modify any of its contents in your `findElementInList` method.

To give an example:

Something like

```
_head.setValue(10);
```

or

```
currentNode = this._head;
currentNode.setValue(10);
```

will modify your head node. In the case of `currentNode.setValue(10);` the contents of `this._head' will be modifiied because of 'aliasing' -- both variables point to the same location.

Important: assigning a new value to the `currentNode` does not modify the value of `this.head` at all. It just lets `currentNode` point to a new node. So

```
currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
```

lets the currentNode point to its postscessor without altering the contents of this._head. This is what is meant by "Java variables pointing to objects are just references".

There are cases, where assignments to a variable will change the variables value:

currentNode.setValue(10);

or

int x = 10;
   x = x + 1; // x == 11

will mutate some value. In the first case you will change the objects content in the second case you are using a so called "primitive value" which is not a reference to some sort of object.